# Is Holder.js a part of Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, holder.js

I was looking at this page: 
[Bootstrap Examples Theme](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/)

at bottom of page the "Carousel" Item, the HTML Code on Line 600:

[Bootstrap : Html Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSldl.jpg)

I want to know if holder.js  is part of Bootstrap Framework or this code use some external js library to display this SVG images.

Comment: Does my answer solved your issue?

Comment: yes ty, i visit that website. :)

Comment: So please can you accept the answer (green mark under votes of the answer)? :)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, [**Bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) only provides its own JS and CSS.

---

As far as I know, [**holder.js**](http://holderjs.com/) is a JavaScript library that you can use to easily generate images of the size of your choice.

I guess Bootstrap used it to make some examples of how carousel renders.